# SQL trigger: I want to make TRIGGER AFTER UPDATE and update it takes data from a different table

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

```
BEGIN
IF new.jenis_transaksi ='Alokasi Keluar'
THEN
 UPDATE prediksi_alokasi SET total_pengeluaran = (
    SELECT SUM(jumlah_alokasi)
    FROM alokasi_dana_desa 
    WHERE jenis_transaksi ='Alokasi Keluar' 
    AND YEAR(tanggal_alokasi) = new.YEAR(tanggal_alokasi)
    AND MONTH(tanggal_alokasi) = new.MONTH(tanggal_alokasi))

WHERE bulan = new.MONTH(tanggal_alokasi);
end if ;
END
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: yes, the query above shows an error in the WHERE bulan = new.MONTH(tanggal_alokasi);

Comment: You should share more information about your question. And please see this link [ask]

Comment: MONTH(new.tanggal_alokasi) possibly

Comment: You must provide: both tables DDLs, full trigger code, sample source tables data and desired final data state. If you receive some error message it must be citated fully.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for the `update`  would be:

```
UPDATE prediksi_alokas pa
    SET total_pengeluaran = (SELECT SUM(add.jumlah_alokasi)
                             FROM alokasi_dana_desa add
                             WHERE add.jenis_transaksi = 'Alokasi Keluar' AND
                                   EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM add.tanggal_alokasi) = EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM new.tanggal_alokasi)
                            )
    WHERE pa.bulan = MONTH(new.tanggal_alokasi);
```

That should at least help the trigger, although there may be other problems as well.